# angular js function runs first time but again gives wrong output

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hope every one is fine,I have an issue with angular Js,I write a function that updates the height of one div in accordance of other div height,As because one div height is adjusted in accordance of the content while other div that contain some content change height which is other div height,The function is,The issue is that its first time run in good manner but after that it gives wrong height.

```
$scope.changeheight=function(){
            //document.getElementById("product").style.height='720px';
            //document.getElementById("buyproduct").style.height='720px';
            angular.element('.buyproduct').css('height', 'auto');
            angular.element('.buyproduct').css('padding-bottom','55px');
            var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('.buyproduct'));
      var height = element[0].clientHeight;
            angular.element('.product').css('height', height);
}</i>
```

Comment: Can you create a sample with your issue in plunker ?

Comment: How about give a class using 'ng-class'?